# MMDrawerViewController set up

Tags: ios, objective-c, mmdrawercontroller

I'm trying to set up a pod called `MMDrawerViewController` which creates a sliding drawer. I have a navigation controller that has a few table view controllers in it's stack. I inserted this in the `NavigationViewController.m` file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Initializing the MMDrawerController views
    UIViewController * leftDrawer = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UIViewController* centerViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

    MMDrawerController * drawerController = [[MMDrawerController alloc] initWithCenterViewController:centerViewController leftDrawerViewController:leftDrawer];
}
```

However when I put this in I get the following error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MMDrawerController", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in NavigationViewController.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command failed with
>   exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Is there something different I should be doing?

Comment: Check in the 'Compile Sources' build phase of your project and see if `MMDrawerController.m` is being compiled. Also, check if you are importing the `MMDrawerController.h` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm posting this as an answer so that this question is no longer unanswered.

You are experiencing this problem because your project is not compiling the `MMDrawerController.m` file which you use in `NavigationViewController.m`. Also, make sure that you are importing `MMDrawerController.h` into `NavigationViewController.m`.